# Phantomjs to Casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to translate my Phantomjs test into Capserjs. The Phantom code navigates to a url with an iframe and then inject some js into the iframe and then it evaluates some javascript from the iframe, which makes a new element appear on the main frame. Running "test.execute();" makes a new div appear on the main frame. The following code works fine.

Phantom:

```
open('http://localhost:1336', function() {
waitFor(function () {
    if (page.injectJs('./public/javascript/jquery-2.1.1.min.js')) {
        return page.evaluate(function() {
            return $('iframe#tab_1').is(':visible');
        });
    }
}, function() {
     waitFor(function() {
         page.switchToFrame(0);
         if (page.injectJs('./public/javascript/jquery-2.1.1.min.js') && page.injectJs('./public/javascript/test.js')) {
             var test = page.evaluate(function () {
                return window.document.title;
             });
             return test == 'IFrameName';
         }
    }, function() {
        var ret = page.evaluate(function () {
            test.execute(); // a function from the injected test.js
        });
        waitFor(function() {
            page.switchToParentFrame();
            return page.evaluate(function() {
                return $('div#tabheader_2').is(':visible');
            });
        }, function() {
            console.log('pass!');
            phantom.exit();
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to rewrite the Phantom code into casperjs by doing the following:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: [
        './public/javascript/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'
    ]
});
casper.start('http://localhost:1336', function() {
    this.echo('1');
});
casper.waitForSelector('iframe#tab_1', function() {
    this.echo('2');
});
casper.withFrame(0, function() {
    this.echo('3');
    var ret = casper.page.injectJs('./public/javascript/test.js');
    this.echo(ret);
    casper.evaluate(function() {
        test.execute();
   });
    this.echo('5');
});
casper.waitForSelector('div#tabheader_2', function() {
    this.echo('pass');
});
casper.run();
```

But it test.execute(); never successfully occurs (output is 1 2 3 true 5). Can anyone spot what is wrong here?  Is there a way for me to check if I'm executing my js on the iframe and not the main frame by mistake? Is there some way to get an error message?

Comment: Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. Maybe run it with the `--web-security=false` flag.

Comment: After listening to the events, it appears my injections are not working properly. That's odd though because the inject returns true. Thanks for the help!